# Slurm Zombiejob cleanup for multiprog uses

Tags: slurm

I'm faced with the following problem:

my module needs to administrate a number of jobs on a Slurm administered cluster. The whole batch is started using --multiprog.

One of them uses rabbitMQ connections, and sadly can't be finished gracefully (not my decision to make). As a result, this sub-job will leave behind a "zombie" job whenever the whole batch is shut down by slurm. To make matters worse, it sends an heartbeat keeping rabbitMQ connections alive and so on.

In essence I need to go on a zombie hunt after each and every job. I tried to do this with a simple epilog (killall -9 -f ), but apparently the epilog doesn't get the complete nodelist, so can't apply "turn undead" to all nodes this job has used.

Neither do I seem to get the complete nodelist for all multiprog-subjobs from the env variables in the batchfile.

I could get the subjobs to send me their nodes... but that would require changes in the subjobs code which I can't do myself, nor can allways guarantee for the future. 
I've also looked into running the jobs from the same batch instead of --multiprog ... but that option comes with its own can of worms.

So the best solution would be one that can be done without having to resort to those two things.

Does anyone have experience with such a situation and could suggest hooks for a solution?

Comment: Are you administrator of the cluster or regular user?

Comment: I'm a regular user. I've solved the problem for now by "avoiding" zombie jobs (hint: slurm doesn't handle shell scripts in the batchfile too well).
But given that there is still a risk of zombies raising their head, I'd be interested in tried solutions for my daily "janitor" service.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by finding the solution of the zombie job.

Slurm doesn't handle shell scripts in the batchfile too well. We used them to "circumvent" the SSH 255 char limitation. Sadly they introduced shadow jobs, which couldn't be stopped by lurm, and thus kept the zombies alife.

So how to use multiprocs with more than 255 chars? Variables. You can export variables in the batchfile, and use them in a bash script in the multiprog file. This does significantly reduce readability (and thus maintenability) of the multiprog files. But once the bash has run, it's gone -> no zombies.